# Why are both items of groups highlighting despite clicked one item of the group in expandableListView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I created a navigation drawer which has occured with an expandableListView. I have two groups.(Group-1, Group-2) For example, When i clicked (group-1, index-2), its view is highlighted but also (group-2, index-1) view is highlighted. Here is my child click listener:

```
 // Listview on child click listener
  expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

      @Override
      public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
              int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
          Toast.makeText(
                  getApplicationContext(),
                  listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                          + " : "
                          + listDataChild.get(
                                  listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                  childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                  .show();    

        int index = parent.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForChild(groupPosition, childPosition));
     parent.setItemChecked(index, true);


    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(expListView);
          return false;
      }
  });
```

Why should i do ? Why both group items were highlighted?

Comment: http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2013/10/android-highlighting-selected-item-in.html - Refer this link, hope this may help

Comment: I applied something like that. My problem is different.I updated my question header.

Comment: I solved my problem. I use v.setSelected(true); instead of int index = parent.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForChild(groupPosition, childPosition)); parent.setItemChecked(index, true);

Now it runs that i want. When i clicked (group-1, index-2), its view is highlighted and (group-2, index-1) or other index of group aren't changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I use `v.setSelected(true);`  instead of `int index = parent.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForChild(groupPosition, childPosition));
     parent.setItemChecked(index, true);`

Now it runs that i want. When i clicked (group-1, index-2), its view is highlighted and (group-2, index-1) or other index of group aren't changed.